# Is it possible to create a solid from PVDF solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I am working on a project where I am attempting to line an aluminium tube with PVDF. The finished wall thickness is required to be 4mm thick.

I have investigated such processes as injection moulding and lining, however due to the complex bends and turns of the finished tube as well as the termination of this into a four port bulkhead, it rules these processes out. I have been working on producing a PVDF solution using DMF solvent so I can cast or mould the lining, however when using heat to draw off the solvent I am only left with a membrane as opposed to a solid. I have also experimented heating the solution and holding under vacuum this also produces an inconsistent structure.

I have read numerous studies on PVDF solution casting and the various solvents to use, however they are all focused on producing membranes for piezo electronics.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But for the actual problem, Googling "PVDF liner" yields a number of PVDF-lined pipe suppliers.

Comment: Many Thanks Jon however liners will not suit my application, hence my reason for wanting to "cast". The pipes terminate in bulk head distribution system and all exposed surfaces will require protection.

Comment: Yes, which is precisely the sorts of things that the providers of PVDF-lined pipes are good at - consider a large chemical plant and all the piping.